# How to Bind a ReportViewer to an IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, reporting, reportviewer

I´m starting to use MS-Report and I would want to know if it is possible to bind a ReportViewer component directly to an IEnumerable collection, instead of creating a DataSourceControl (ObjectDataSource, EntityDataSource, SqlDataSource, etc...), in a similar way as we do with databound components (using the Datasource property instead of DataSourceID). I know that the ReportViewer don´t have a "DataSource" property, but I´m wondering if there is a suchlike way.

In my case I´m using a nTier application with repository pattern and Entity Framework (POCO EF 4.1).

Thanks!

Comment: did you check Using a Business Object Data Source with the ReportViewer Web Server Control in Local Processing Mode?[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251692.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a reportDataSource for your report (using the designer). You will asked for a name of the reportDateSource and a type (the type of the entities of your IEnumerable collection)(lets suposse you named id 'test' and your datatype is Client)

```
ReportDataSource reportDataSource = New ReportDataSource("test", listofclients);
localreport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
```

That's all.

Comment: Thank you @Jonathan. It helps a lot and makes the things easier!